# Can I reset my IMac to factory settings without loss of data?

Tags: osx-lion

Is there a way of resetting my IMac to factory settings without losing any data.  Following an upgrade my address book seems corrupted and I am having other problems including my email address being abbreviated  every time I enter it into a dialogue box. Basically I want to restore my machine to the settings I had when I bought it.

Comment: This is a tough question - you do realize factory settings means having none of your data.

Answer (score 4):

Well you can export you data to an external device then re-import it after you reset you machine to factory settings.

If you have a DVD-burner you could create a system image or data backup of your  personal files.

I  would go threw my personal files and copy them to an external USB, firewire or use my DVD burner or ipad first and then do a factory reset.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a backup via time-machine which will hold all your data and personal settings (hopefully not the corrupted ones) and is built into the OS X operating system. Then download and install mavericks onto a USB or DVD and proceed to boot and install a fresh from there. Once you have the fresh OS you will be able to recover your backup form your time machine save. Hope this helps